# With Geometry Nodes is there any way to align the Pivot Point of an instanced objects with the Geometry Nodes point?

Tags: geometry-nodes

What I want is for the instanced object's *Pivot Point* [actually origin - ed] to align with the *Geometry Nodes* point with is instancing it.

**The objects *Pivot Point*:**
[image]

**This is what it gives me:**
[image]

**And this is what I want:**
[image]

**My node setup:**
[image]

Thank you!

Comment: What exactly are you asking?  What you're showing in your picture seems to be the instances, rotated in the same way that the points are rotated-- rotated about the pivot of each point.  What pivot do you want?  Maybe you could make a quick pic of something like what you're after?  (It's probably possible to do.)

Comment: It's still not clear after the edit, could you add a diagram or an example of what you're trying to do ?

Comment: Edited the question and hope it's more clear.
I noticed that what I was asking was actualy not even what I wanted.

Comment: I think it's because of the point scale that is in float, i jut make your same set up and it's working correctly, the only difference is the point scale, mine is in Vector. [here](https://imgur.com/a/mZ1b4aZ)

Comment: Wow @Emir, thank you!
But now I wonder why?